# How to recursively side by side diff directories with line numbers in the diff in unix?

Tags: directory, xargs, diff, recursive

My scenario is to perform side by side diff directories using:

```
diff -ry <folder1> <folder2>
```

**along with the line numbers in the diff output**. By default line numbers are not displayed in the side by side diff and the parameter `--new-line-format` doesn't work along with `diff -y` only works with `diff -u`.

What i have tried is to do [For files only]:

```
diff -y <(cat -n file1) <(cat -n file2)
```

to generate line numbers. The above command first generates line numbers and then passes it to diff command, so the line numbers are kept intact in the diff result.

But when it comes to use `diff -ry`, i am unable to do it. Is there any way to apply cat -n using something like `xargs` [like a preprocessor] in the `diff -ry` command ?

Comment: This is a re-iteration of a [previous post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306238/117516).  It didn't get any more meaningful in the mean time, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert inline `diff -ru`  output into a side-by-side presentation, *with line numbers* and colour using the python program `cdiff` also known as [cdiff.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cdiff/0.9.6) (not to be confused with the `cdiff` wrapper that is part of `colordiff`), by Matthew Wang.

Follow any of the suggested installation methods given in the link, or just extract the `cdiff.py` script from the download into your PATH, then you can do

```
diff -ru dir1 dir2 | cdiff.py -s
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your solution is good but cdiff shows some unwanted information like --- ./myfolder1/subfolder2/myfile.txt   2016-03-30 13:10:25.403649965 -0400
+++ ./myfolder2/subfolder2/myfile.txt   2016-08-14 10:16:08.590097212 -0400 which i don't want. Secondly, it would be nice if i can use any native command for the cause.

Answer (score 1):

[Stephen Harris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306238/80216#306241) has given a very good answer
to the [previous version of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306238/80216). 
Unfortunately, it cannot handle the pathological case
of filenames with newlines in them. 
Here is a minor adaptation of his answer that handles that case. 
(I've also changed it to use `cat -n` instead of `nl`,
and to use the `-y` option to `diff`.)

```
find folder1 -type f -exec bash -c 'for file1
do
  file2="${file1/folder1/folder2}"
  echo "Comparing $file1 to $file2"
  diff -y <(cat -n "$file1") <(cat -n "$file2")
done' bash {} +
```

Since you asked for an `xargs` solution in a comment on Stephen’s answer,
here you go:

```
find folder1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'for file1
do
  file2="${file1/folder1/folder2}"
  echo "Comparing $file1 to $file2"
  diff -y <(cat -n "$file1") <(cat -n "$file2")
done' bash
```

Note that these commands must be done in `bash`,
because the POSIX shell doesn’t support
`${parameter/pattern/string}`,
and the `xargs` solution must be done in GNU-land,
because POSIX doesn’t support `find -print0` or `xargs -0`. 
(Of course, you could replace `-print0` with `-print` and drop the `-0`,
but then you’d lose the capability to handle filenames
with newlines in them.)

Comment: The above solutions will fail miserably because the above technique is unable to find the files which are only in $file2. The above command traverses through the subfolders which contain only in $file1. What if there are some new files in $file2 and not in $file1 ?

Comment: What if there are some files in `folder2` and not in `folder1`? What do you want done with them? Your previous question (of which this is a rewrite) said something about comparing same to same, so `folder1/alpha` should be compared to `folder2/alpha`, `folder1/beta` should be compared to `folder2/beta`, etc. You have never said what to do if  `folder1/gamma` exists and `folder2/gamma` doesn't, or `folder2/iota` exists and `folder1/iota` doesn't, etc. Please don't say that my answer "will fail miserably" because it fails to satisfy a requirement that you didn't state. I can't read your mind.